# Best way to manage multiple category in database design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Objective: To design a best database table for a Trip

Table 01 : `Trip (Columns: id, transport_mode_id....etc)`

Table 02: `Trains (id, name, number....etc.)`

Table 03: `Buses(id, name, number....etc)`

I want to design a `Trip table (transport_mode_id)` with either `train_id` or `bus_id`. Trip should have either `bus_id` or `train_id`.

Should I create a two columns `train_id`, `bus_id` ? in the Trip table. Please suggest to design a `trip` table

Comment: It seems you should look into a [Trip belongs_to :transportation_mode, polymorphic: true](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) association.

Comment: If you ride  a bus to a train is that a trip? IE can a trip have many buses and trains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [polymorphic-associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) Sometimes trip links to a bus, other times to a train, and planes, and boats.

> A slightly more advanced twist on associations is the polymorphic association. With polymorphic associations, a model can belong to more than one other model, on a single association. For example, you might have a trip model that belongs to either a train model or a bus model. Here's how this could be declared:

```
class Trip < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to : transportable, polymorphic: true
end

class Bus < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trips, as: :transportable
end

class Train < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trips, as: :transportable
end
```

on the Database

```
class CreateTrips < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :trips do |t|
      ...
      t.references :transportable, polymorphic: true, index: true
      ....
    end
  end
end
```

if the table all ready exists

```
class CreateTrips < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :trips, :transportable, polymorphic: true, index: true
  end
emd
```

I hope that this helps

Comment: No problem just pay it forward